# Google Search Console, Ownership verification failing

Tags: google-search-console

I am trying to add/verify a wordpress site that I am managing (Through HTML file, HTML tag and Google Analytics) but I keep getting the error below:

**Ownership verification failed**
**Verification method: HTML file**
**Failure reason: The connection to your server timed out.**

Any Idea how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Failure reason**: The connection to your server timed out.

1. This implies that the URL for verification is wrong.
2. or Server is responding slow or it's down

**Solution**

1. Check the verification URL is accessible in the browser. If not then something is wrong with the file, may it doesn't have the necessary permission.
2. Maybe your website disallow robots to craw .
3. check if the name of the file is the same as downloaded from the google search console.

If problems still exist, use alternative ways to verify

1. **HTML tag** Add a meta tag to your site's home page
2. **Google Analytics** Use your Google Analytics account
3. **Google Tag Manager** Use your Google Tag Manager account
4. **Domain name provider** Associate a DNS record with Google